# If there is a process to set Session in Controller executed by test using PHPUnit, error will be issued and it will fail

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.8

If there is a process to set Session in Controller executed by test using PHPUnit, error "Session store not set on request" will be issued and it will fail.

PHP 7.1
Larval 5.8
PHPunit 7.5

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('id');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    // I intend to succeed..
    //$Client = App::make('Client');
    //$res = $Client->authenticate($email, $password);
    $res = true;
    if ($res) {
      $token = "sampletoken";
      $request->session()->put('Authorization', $token);
      return redirect()
        ->intended('/list');
    }
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Mockery;

class LoginControllerTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testAuth()
  {
    $request = new Request();
    $request->merge([
        "id" => "test_id",
        "password" => "test_pass"
    ]);
    $controller = new LoginController();
    $response = $controller->auth($request);
    $this->assertEquals(preg_match('/\/list/', $response->getTargetUrl()), 1);
  }
}
```

```
1) Tests\Feature\LoginControllerTest::testAuth
RuntimeException: Session store not set on request
```

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your test `setUp` method, you can set the session on the request, and tell it to use the `array` driver so that it isn't persisted:

```php
$this->app['request']->setSession($this->app['session']->driver('array'));
```

Comment: This results in an error: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setSession() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface, instance of Illuminate\Session\Store given

Comment: Source for this answer was probably: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9632#issuecomment-122070654

Comment: Since (I think) Laravel 5.5 it's no more called `setSession` but `setLaravelSession`.